# UIImagePickerController bug when tap button home iphone

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using `UIImagePickerController` to take a photo. I set `allowsEditing` and `showsCameraControls` property of `UIImagePickerController` to `YES`.

After I take a photo and the "Use/Retake" screen appears, I press the Home button of iPhone.

[image]

After I reopen app, I have a bug. The camera screen shows again:

[image]

I don't know why?

Comment: What device and version of iOS are you testing this on? I just tried to replicate this and I don't see this problem.

Comment: i'm ussing iphone5, iOS 8.1